# My getToken function doesn't work on the first call

Tags: c, token

I've written this function for a homework assignment I'm doing in school:

```
char* getToken(char buffer[], int pos)
{
    int i; 
    char copy[350], *token, *del = ",\n"; 

    strcpy(copy, buffer); 
    token = strtok(copy, del); 

    for (i = 1; i < pos; i++) 
        token = strtok(NULL, del); 

    return token; 
}
```

I want it to return a token at a given position without corrupting the original character array. The issue is that it return garbage on the first call, yet it works as expected on all subsequent calls. This should be a very simple fix, but I've been coding all day and I need a fresh set of eyes to back me up. (The hardcoded 350 is a given in this homework assignment, buffer shouldn't exceed 349 characters)

Comment: `token` point to part of local auto variable. Also `token` need NULL check

Comment: To make the function work, the `copy` array either needs to be `static`, or you need to pass the `copy` array to the function. As is, the `copy` array disappears as soon as the function returns, and so the returned pointer is not valid.

Comment: @user3386109: Or `malloc()` `copy`.

Comment: @EOF Yup, but then things get complicated (because the returned pointer isn't at the start of the malloc'd memory), as shown in MikeCAT's answer :)

Comment: @user3386109: Making `copy` `static` is even worse in terms of the complications that it causes.

Comment: @EOF Valid point. If `copy` is `static`, then the function is not reentrant, and the returned pointer becomes invalid as soon as the function is called again. I should have put that disclaimer in my comment.

Comment: @user3386109: Huh? The pointer to a `static` object *doesn't* become *invalid* the next time the function is called. The value of the object may change unexpectedly though, which is the reason global state is so nasty.

Comment: @EOF The returned pointer becomes invalid because the memory that it was pointing to has been overwritten with new data. So the returned pointer no longer has any useful meaning.

Comment: @user3386109: The pointer retains its meaning. It *still* points to the same valid object, within the object's lifetime (because the lifetime is the lifetime of the program). You *can* write code that meaningfully uses this. It's just not convenient or nice.

Comment: @EOF *"You can write code that meaningfully uses this."* That's a real stretch given that the pointer points to some random position in the middle of a buffer whose contents have been overwritten.

Comment: @user3386109: No, the stretch is claiming that the pointer has become "invalid" in any sense of the word. The values of objects pointed to by pointers change all the time, and the pointers remain valid. The changes *do not have to happen through the pointer either*, in C you can freely alias pointers to compatible types (and character types...). C leaves a lot of things "undefined", but this is not one of them. The pointer is valid.

Comment: @EOF To paraphrase the mad hatter, "The word means what I think it means, because I'm the one who used it."

Comment: @user3386109 If you feel like giving a definition of "valid" that is meaningful, correct with regards to the standard, doesn't make most C-code in the world "invalid" and makes *this* use "invalid", I'd *really* like to hear it.

Comment: @EOF A valid pointer in this context would be a pointer to a token returned by the `getToken` function.

Comment: @user3386109: So the pointer might well remain valid even in your (not general or meaningful) definition, if the next `getToken()`-call returns  the same pointer (which can easily happen if the length and number of tokens in the buffer are the same across calls).

Comment: @EOF Indeed, it may well remain valid (using my meaning of the word), and so we have gone full circle, and all the OP needs to do is declare the `copy` array as `static` (keeping in mind all of the ramifications that we have discussed in these comments).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are returning pointer pointing non-static local variable, which will vanish on returning from the function and dereferencing the returned pointer from caller will invoke *undefined behavior*.

I guess you should copy the token before returning. Add `#include <stdlib.h>` to use `malloc()` and `free()`.

```
char* getToken(const char buffer[], int pos)
{
    int i; 
    char *copy, *token, *ret, *del = ",\n"; 

    copy = malloc(strlen(buffer) + 1); /* for string longer than 349 bytes is passed */
    if (copy == NULL) return NULL;
    strcpy(copy, buffer); 
    token = strtok(copy, del); 

    for (i = 1; i < pos; i++) 
        token = strtok(NULL, del); 

    ret = malloc(strlen(token) + 1);
    if (ret != NULL) strcpy(ret, token); /* copy string before freeing it */
    free(copy); /* if you use malloc(), use free() */
    return ret;
}
```